# JSONSchema - Element can appear alone or within a group

Tags: json, jsonschema, json-schema-validator

I have a JSON that looks like this:

```
{
    "name": "Jane",
    "company_name": "BrandNewStartup",
    "designation": "DesignLead"
}
```

The `name` element can appear alone in the JSON as well, so the following JSON is valid too.

```
{
    "name": "Jane"
}
```

But `company_name` and `designation` cannot appear if `name` is missing. So the following JSON should be invalid:

```
{
    "company_name": "BrandNewStartup",
    "designation": "DesignLead"
}
```

I have tried the following rule:

```
"oneOf": [
      {
          "required": [
              "name",
              "company_name",
              "designation"
           ]
      },
      {
           "required": [
              "name"
           ]
      }
]
```

However this does not seem to work (e.g [this validation library](https://github.com/networknt/json-schema-validator) raises error that *the JSON should be valid to only one schema but it is valid against all*).

If I change this to `anyOf`, the first JSON with all the 3 fields works, but when `name` appears alone, an error is raised that the `company_name` `designation` fields are missing.

How do I define this rule?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

JSON Schema is a constraints based language. Anything you don't specify is allowed.

The `required` keyword means a key is required in an object, but doesn't inherintly prevent any other keys from being included.

Breaking down the schema in your question, when you have all three keys in your object, as in your first example instance, then both subschemas in `oneOf` would be valid.

In order to restrict the allowed properties, you need to use the `additionalProperties` keyword, which in your case also means you need to use the `properties` keyword. `required` has no effect on `additionalProperties`.

The second subschema needs to only be valid when the instance has ONLY `name` and no other keys. Here's a live demo using the below modified JSON Schema: https://jsonschema.dev/s/7JcUa

```
{
  "$schema": "http://json-schema.org/draft-07/schema",
  "oneOf": [
    {
      "required": [
        "name",
        "company_name",
        "designation"
      ]
    },
    {
      "required": [
        "name"
      ],
      "properties": {
        "name": true
      },
      "additionalProperties": false
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: I greatly appreciate this thorough explanation. Thank you.

Comment: You're welcome. Feel free to buy me a coffee using the link in my bio. No expectations =]